Spring Boot 3.2.4 - REST controller: Retrieve/Update/Delete with @IdClass composite primary key defined in JPA entity
The focus of my question is about writing an @GetMapping, @PutMapping and @DeleteMapping in a REST controller called UserProfileController.java that should include multiple path variables in a single request such as "/userprofiles/1/2". The first variable is assigned the Id of a user related to the parent User entity primary key, the second variable is assigned the Id of a profile from the parent Profile entity primary key. Together those two variables define the composite primary key of the UserProfile entity and identifies a unique user profile. To achieve this, I created a UserProfileKey class that I implemented as an @IdClass in the UserProfile entity.

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.Objects;

    // Define a composite primary key class

    public class UserProfileKey implements Serializable {

    private int userLoginId;
    private int userProfileId;

    // Default constructor

    public UserProfileKey(int userLoginId,int userProfileId) {
        this.userLoginId = userLoginId;
        this.userProfileId = userProfileId;
    }

    // equals and hashcode

     @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        UserProfileKey userProfileKey = (UserProfileKey) o;
        return Objects.equals(userLoginId, userProfileKey.userLoginId)
        && Objects.equals(userProfileId, userProfileKey.userProfileId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(userLoginId,
                            userProfileId);
    }

    // Hibernate requires a default no-argument constructor. We make it protected since          our application

    // code shoud never use that constructor directly.

    // protected UserProfileKey() {
    // }
    
}

The entity UserProfile is as follows:

    package com.mekong.g2g.administration.prf;

import java.util.Objects;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.mekong.g2g.administration.rrp.Profile;
import com.mekong.g2g.administration.usr.User;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.IdClass;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
//import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@IdClass(UserProfileKey.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Table(name = "tab_user_profiles", 
       uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"usrprf_login_id",
                                                          "usrprf_profile_id"}))
public class UserProfile {

    @Id 
    @Column(name="usrprf_login_id", nullable=false, columnDefinition = "INT(11)")
    private UserProfileKey userLoginId;

    @Id 
    @Column(name="usrprf_profile_id", nullable=false, columnDefinition = "INT(11)")
    private UserProfileKey userProfileId;

    @Column(name="usrprf_workgroup_id", nullable=false, columnDefinition = "INT(11)")
    private Long userWorkgroupId;

    @Column(name="usrprf_profile_ok", nullable=false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)")
    private boolean userProfileOk;

    // Relationships

    // A user profile refers to only one user account

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="usrprf_login_id", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false )
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    // A user profile refers to only one profile

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="usrprf_profile_id", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false )
    private Profile profile;

    public Profile getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }

    public void setProfile(Profile profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }

    // A user profile is associated to only one workgroup
    

    // Getters and setters

    public UserProfileKey getUserLoginId() {
        return userLoginId;
    }

    public void setUserLoginId(UserProfileKey userLoginId) {
        this.userLoginId = userLoginId;
    }

    public UserProfileKey getUserProfileId() {
        return userProfileId;
    }

    public void setUserProfileId(UserProfileKey userProfileId) {
        this.userProfileId = userProfileId;
    }

    public Long getUserWorkgroupId() {
        return userWorkgroupId;
    }

    public void setUserWorkgroupId(Long userWorkgroupId) {
        this.userWorkgroupId = userWorkgroupId;
    }

    public boolean getUserProfileOk() {
        return userProfileOk;
    }

    public void setUserProfileOk(boolean userProfileOk) {
        this.userProfileOk = userProfileOk;
    }

     // Two objects are considered equal when they have the same state 

     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object o) {
         if (this == o) return true;
         if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
             return false;
         UserProfile userProfile = (UserProfile) o;
         return Objects.equals(userLoginId, userProfile.userLoginId)
         && Objects.equals(userProfileId, userProfile.userProfileId)
         && Objects.equals(userWorkgroupId, userProfile.userWorkgroupId)
         && Objects.equals(userProfileOk, userProfile.userProfileOk);
     }

      // The hash code is derived from the object's memory address

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(userLoginId,
                            userProfileId,
                            userWorkgroupId,
                            userProfileOk);
    }

    // Define a toString() method for the purpose of logging

    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "-" + getUserLoginId() + "-" + getUserProfileId()+ "-" + getUserWorkgroupId();
    }

    // Hibernate requires a default no-argument constructor. We make it protected since our application
    // code shoud never use that constructor directly.

    protected UserProfile() {
    }

    public UserProfile(UserProfileKey userLoginId,
                       UserProfileKey userProfileId,
                       Long userWorkgroupId,
                       boolean userProfileOk) {
        this.userLoginId = userLoginId; 
        this.userProfileId = userProfileId;
        this.userWorkgroupId = userWorkgroupId;
        this.userProfileOk = userProfileOk;
                   
    }
    
}


My code compiles without error but I am not sure whether the IdClass (UserProfileKey) and the two variables userLoginId and userProfileId in (/userprofiles/1/2) are going to be properly mapped to findById(userProfileKey) when I run the API call. I need an example for @GetMapping to retrieve a single user profile and @Putmapping to update that user profile in this case given the attached code.
Here is the UserProfileController:

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.mekong.g2g.administration.prf.UserProfile;
import com.mekong.g2g.administration.prf.UserProfileKey;
import com.mekong.g2g.administration.prf.UserProfileNotFoundException;
import com.mekong.g2g.administration.prf.UserProfileRepository;

@RestController
public class UserProfileController {

 private final UserProfileRepository repository;

 public UserProfileController(UserProfileRepository repository) {
     this.repository = repository;
 }

 // Aggregate root: retrieve all items
 @GetMapping("/userProfiles")
 public Iterable<UserProfile> getUserProfiles() {
     return repository.findAll();
 }

 // Create
 @PostMapping("/userProfiles")
 UserProfile newUserProfile(@RequestBody UserProfile newUserProfile) {
 return repository.save(newUserProfile);
 
 }

 // Retrieve Single item
 @GetMapping("/userProfiles/{userLoginId}/{userProfileId}")
 UserProfile one(@PathVariable UserProfileKey userProfileKey) {  
     
     return repository.findById(userProfileKey)
     .orElseThrow(() -> new UserProfileNotFoundException(userProfileKey));
 }


 // Update
 //@PutMapping("/userProfiles/{userProfileKey}")
 @PutMapping("/userProfiles/{userLoginId}/{userProfileId}")
 UserProfile replaceUserProfile(@RequestBody UserProfile newUserProfile, @PathVariable UserProfileKey userProfileKey) {
 
 return repository.findById(userProfileKey)
   .map(userProfile -> {
     userProfile.setUserLoginId(newUserProfile.getUserLoginId());
     userProfile.setUserProfileId(newUserProfile.getUserProfileId());
     userProfile.setUserWorkgroupId(newUserProfile.getUserWorkgroupId());
     userProfile.setUserProfileOk(newUserProfile.getUserProfileOk());
     
     return repository.save(userProfile);
   })
   .orElseGet(() -> {
     newUserProfile.setUserLoginId(userProfileKey);
     newUserProfile.setUserProfileId(userProfileKey);
     return repository.save(newUserProfile);
   });
 }

 // Delete
 @DeleteMapping("/userProfiles/{userLoginId}/{userProfileId}")
 // @DeleteMapping("/userProfiles/{userProfileKey}")
 void deleteUserProfile(@PathVariable UserProfileKey userProfileKey) {
     repository.deleteById(userProfileKey);
 }

 
}

Finally we have the UserProfileRepository:

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;

public interface UserProfileRepository extends CrudRepository <UserProfile, UserProfileKey>, 
                                               PagingAndSortingRepository <UserProfile, UserProfileKey> {
  
}

and the UserProfileNotFoundException that is called in the controller:

public class UserProfileNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public UserProfileNotFoundException(UserProfileKey userProfileKey) {
      super("Could not find user profile " + userProfileKey);
    }  
    
}

